# Missing notes on MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, notes.app

I cannot see some of my notes I created on MacBook Air. When I check in Spotlight it says (null).  What does that mean?  Where are my notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to see or recover some of your lost Notes.

Open Terminal and paste this:

```
cd ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes/Data/Library/Notes
strings NotesV1.storedata | grep body | open -f
```

That should show you all your notes in text file, from where you can copy the missing one.

*Terminal is a application located in the Utilities Folder under Applications.*